# AWS Lambda Moving SES Message to different S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

In my SES actions I trigger my Lambda function that essentially checks if a message should be blocked. If it is not blocked, it continues processing rules and is put in our "good" email S3 bucket. If it is blocked, it just stops processing and drops the message. I cannot find a way to "block" a message and have it stored in a "bad" email S3 bucket. Though it may not always be the case, being able to review these if required would be ideal. Is this something that can be invoked within the Lambda function or a way to have a workflow within the SES actions?

Comment: You could put a message in default S3 bucket, create an event trigger to invoke the Lambda function and in the Lambda function check if it should be blocked. If it's ok, do nothing. If it should be blocked, you can copy the message to the "bad bucket" and remove the message from original bucket

Comment: *If it is blocked, it just stops processing and drops the message* what does this mean? Why is the lambda function not able to handle this?

Comment: That is how Lambda functions interact with SES rule flow. They can either stop the specific lambda action execution, stop the entire rule set, or continue.